# error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected in C code

Tags: c, struct, computer-science

I'm trying to write some code, and there is one error I don't understand why I keep getting.
I want to write to a file, and I have some functions to return different information about the struct I have built.
Here is my code:

```
IkResult productWriteToFile(AmountSet inventory, FILE *file){
    if (inventory == NULL) {
        return NULL_ARGUMENT;
    }

    fprintf(file, "Inventory status:\n");

    AS_FOREACH(Product, item, inventory){
        for(Product prod = (Product) asGetFirst(inventory); prod != NULL;
            prod = (Product) asGetNext(inventory)) {
            fprintf(file,"name: %s, id: %d, amount: %.3f, price: %.3f\n", getProductName(prod),
                    (int)getProductId(prod), prod -> amount, (double)((prod -> item) -> prodPrice));
        }
    }


    fclose(file);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

and these are the "helper" functions:

```
unsigned int getProductId(Product prod){
    return (prod -> item) -> id;
}

char* getProductName(Product prod){
    return (prod -> item) -> name;
}
```

These is the error I am getting:

```
In function ‘productWriteToFile’:
item.c:183:21: error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected
                     (int)getProductId(prod), prod -> amount, (double)((prod -> item) -> prodPrice));
```

Anybody knows what's the problem? Please help ><

UPDATE--- the structures are:

```
typedef double (*GetProductPrice)(ProductData, const double amount);
typedef void *ProductData;

struct product_t{
    struct item_t item;
    double amount;
    Product* next;
};

struct item_t{
    char* name;
    int id;
    GetProductPrice prodPrice;
    AmountType type;
    ProductData ProductData;
    CopyData copy;
    FreeData free_data;
};
```

Comment: What type is `prod->amount`?

Comment: Hiding pointers behind typedefs makes the code hard to read, especially as the types are not shown.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorry!! Added here the structures!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp double

Comment: I see a member `Product* next;` but from other code isn't `Product` already a pointer type? There's no definition of many of the types.

Comment: ok, so what's the definition of `GetProductPrice`?

Comment: The `(prod -> item) -> prodPrice` suggests the `item` is a pointer, but it isn't, it's a `struct`.

Comment: `Product* next;` makes me think `Product` is not a pointer typedef, but you are using it everywhere as if it is. But then that would be causing a bunch of other errors....

Comment: @dbush GetProductPrice is a void* - another struct but one that should come from the user.

Comment: @SpaceNugget So you're casing a `void *` to a `double`.  That's your problem.,

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the product is a linked set- part of an AmountSet- a set that contains items and amounts, plus has an iterator

Comment: @dbush sorry the GetProductPrice is a double

Comment: Note that you don't need parentheses with `->`; it's `(*).`, which does need parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `prodPrice` member has type `GetProductPrice`, whose type is as follows:

```
typedef double (*GetProductPrice)(ProductData, const double amount);
```

This is type is not `double`, but a pointer to a function that returns a `double`.  So you need to call the function.

```
prod->item->prodPrice(prod->item->ProductData, prod->amount)
```